# Properties of functors $\mathcal{C} \rightarrow (\mathcal{D}^{\rightarrow})^{\rightarrow}$

Tags: category-theory

I've found some sources stating that for two natural transformations $\alpha, \beta: F \rightarrow G$, no non-trivial modifications can be found in standard categories. However, it is possible to define natural transformations as functors $\alpha, \beta: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}^{\rightarrow}$ if $F,G:\mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$. So why don't we investigate functors $\mathcal{C} \rightarrow (\mathcal{D}^{\rightarrow})^{\rightarrow}$, and treat them as natural transformations between natural transformations (seen as functors)?

If I understand correctly, objects in $(\mathcal{D}^{\rightarrow})^{\rightarrow}$ correspond to commuting squares in $\mathcal{D}$ and arrows to commuting cubes. Is that correct? If yes, then this gives rise to four functors $F,F',G,G':\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ with two natural transformations $\alpha:F\rightarrow G, \beta:F'\rightarrow G'$ and a "modification" $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$ with components being the edges of the cube that connect the naturality squares of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Does this lead to non-trivial structures? Also, how does this correspond to the idea of modifications in higher category theory?

Answer (score 0):

"Modification" is actually a technical term  from 3-category theory ([nLab reference](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/modification)).

As an organizational philosophy, I think the better perspective on natural transformations is that the functor category $\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C}$ is a fundamental notion, and that natural transformations are simply the arrows of $\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C}$.

Since $\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C}$ is simply a category, it doesn't have (nontrivial) 2-arrows between its arrows.

---

Note that assuming that functors form the objects of an exponential $\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C}$, we can determine the arrows by the product-exponential adjunction.

Let $\mathbf{2}$ be the arrow category $\bullet \to \bullet$. There are (natural) bijections

$$ \mathrm{Arr}(\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C})
\cong \mathrm{Funct}(\mathbf{2}, \mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C})
\cong \mathrm{Funct}(\mathbf{2} \times \mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D})
\cong \mathrm{Funct}(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}^\mathbf{2})
$$

By the third term, we see that natural transformations can be expressed as functors $\mathbf{2} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$. Your description of them appears in the fourth term.

Comment: So what I have constructed is not a modification because it goes between natural transformations that go between different functors, right? I am actually interested in the arrows of the arrow category of the functor category, i.e. commuting squares where the arrows are natural transformations. So my question is, are these objects of any use? Do they have interesting properties? What about the n-th iteration of taking the arrow category?